# Sql Case Statement implementation in ElasticSearch NEST client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working on Elasticsearch NEST Client for .NET.
I have to implement a CASE statement quivaleitn query in ES.

```
CASE 
WHEN [CompanyId] <> 1 AND VisibilityId=1 AND [Publish] = 1 AND StatusId = 1 THEN 1
WHEN [OrganizationId] = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END = 1
```

Clearly I have no idea how to this. I am being reserching for the past 2 days but nothing found.

can it be used with Terms Filter as I did in earlier lines like:

```
new FilterDescriptor<MyClass>()
                                .Term("OrganizationId", 1)
```

Comment: I have achieved it by combination of Bool Query and OR Filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved it by combining `Bool Query` and `Or Filter` as :

```
new FilterDescriptor<ListingViewDTO>()
        .Or(fo => fo.Bool(b => b.Must(c => c.And(
                fs => !fs.Term("OrganizationId", compositeFilter.OrganizationId),
                fs => fs.Query(q => q.Fuzzy(n => n.OnField("ListingAttributeDTO.AttributeName").Value("ListingPublish"))),
                fs => fs.Query(q => q.Fuzzy(n => n.OnField("ListingAttributeDTO.Value").Value("1"))),
                fs => fs.Term("VisibilityId", (int)Visibility.AnyOne),
                fs => fs.Term("StatusId", 2)))),
            fo => fo.Term("OrganizationId", compositeFilter.OrganizationId));
```